# Use qiskit-experiments StateTomographyAnalysis on data previously recorded without qiskit

Tags: qiskit, state-tomography

I would like to use the analysis capabilities of qiskit, i.e. `StateTomographyAnalysis` of qiskit_experiments on data that were previously measured on a system not using Qiskit.

So what I have is a quantum state with an unknown state preparation (I know the goal, but not what actually happened) and can therefore not model a circuit to prepare the state.

After receiving that state, I measured, using different rotations, to get a measurement in all Pauli bases.

So the circuits would look like this:

```
cZ = QuantumCircuit(1)
# unknown part here
cZ.save_statevector()
cZ.measure_all()

cX = QuantumCircuit(1)
# unknown part here
cX.save_statevector()
cX.ry(-np.pi/2,0)
cX.measure_all()

cY = QuantumCircuit(1)
# unknown part here
cY.save_statevector()
cY.rx(np.pi/2,0)
cY.measure_all()
```

The 'unknown part' is the same in all circuits, the `save_statevector()` is where I would like to reconstruct the density matrix.

Now these circuits were actually measured on a real quantum computer that does not use qiskit and all i am left with is the final data, like this:

Shots: 1k

| Basis | 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $\sigma_Z$ | 0.49 | 0.51 |
| $\sigma_X$ | 0.98 | 0.02 |
| $\sigma_Y$ | 0.51 | 0.49 |

On these sample data I can immediately see that this must be close to $|+\rangle$, the real world example is a bit more complicated (and involves 2 qubits).

I would like to use the `StateTomographyAnalysis` to fit a density matrix to the given results and further process the data, and tried this approach:

```
from qiskit_experiments.library.tomography import StateTomographyAnalysis
from qiskit_experiments.framework.experiment_data import ExperimentData

outcomes = {
    'X': {'0':0.98, '1':0.02},
    'Y': {'0':0.51, '1':0.49},
    'Z': {'0':0.49, '1':0.51},
}

exData = ExperimentData().add_data(outcomes)

tomo = StateTomographyAnalysis().run(exData)
```

This gives an error about 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_created_in_db', but also found the documentation hard to understand.

How could I do this? I guess adding the data to an `ExperimentData` object is not as simple as I tried it....

I'm using qiskit-experiments-0.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while to figure out:

```
from qiskit.result import Result
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit_experiments.framework import ExperimentData
from qiskit_experiments.library import StateTomography
from qiskit_experiments.library.tomography import StateTomographyAnalysis

# counts like {'0x1': 225, '0x0': 280, '0x2': 249, '0x3': 270}
# m_idx is list of pauli basis indices, e.g. [0,1] for ZX
def getSingleResDict(shots, counts, bits, m_idx):
    return {
        'shots': shots,
        'success': True,
        'data': {'counts': counts},
        'header': {
            'creg_sizes': [['c_tomo', bits]],
            'memory_slots': bits,
            'metadata': {'clbits': list(range(bits)), 'cond_clbits': None, 'm_idx': m_idx}
        },
    }

def getResDict(results):
    return {
        'backend_name': '',
        'backend_version': '',
        'qobj_id': '',
        'job_id': '',
        'success': True,
        'results': results
        }

dct = getResDict(
    [
        getSingleResDict(
            100,
            {'0x0':49, '0x1':51},
            1,
            [0]
            ),
        getSingleResDict(
            100,
            {'0x0':98, '0x1':2},
            1,
            [1]
            ),
        getSingleResDict(
            100,
            {'0x0':51, '0x1':49},
            1,
            [2]
            ),
    ]
)

result = Result.from_dict(dct)

circ = QuantumCircuit(1)

# QST Experiment
tomo = StateTomography(circ)
exdata = ExperimentData(tomo)
exdata.add_data(result)
StateTomographyAnalysis().run(exdata)
exdata.analysis_results()
```

Versions used:

- Python 3.11
- qiskit 0.44.0
- qiskit-experiments 0.5.1
- qiskit-aer 0.13.1 (probably not relevant)